# Search in view results causes xpage to be blank

Tags: xpages

I have a view panel in which I have the formula:
  isParent = "1" set for Search In View Results.

This cause the whole xpgae to show as blank page, I have lots of other things on the page , in addition to the view panel, but nothing is displayed

What is being shown for the source of the page is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv=Content-Type></HEAD>
<BODY></BODY></HTML>
ate
```

I am not sure where the "ate" is coming from.  When page is displayed normaly, there is "corporate" displayed on the page, prehaps it is form there.

I am unable to find documentation on this property so I am unsure if I am even using it correctly but you would still think some of the page would display or at least an error.

What I will probably do is to create another view with isParent = "1" in the select frumala but it would still be nice to know why this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this search uses the full text search functionality you have to search for

```
[isParent] = "1"
```

instead. I assume you are looking for all documents which have "1" in field "isParent".

It throws an error "Query is not understandable" if you use your original  search string. I don't know why it doesn't show the error in your case. Do you use a special XPages runtime error page? It would throw an error too if database is not full text indexed.

Comment: That worked great.  Also my answer below.  Yours is more simple.   I do no have a special xPage runtime page.  And I am returning runtime errors.  The solution below seems to work for me. Don't know whay it is not displaying an error.

Comment: Great... and I was with my answer earlier again :) - Is application property "Display XPages Runtime Error Page" set for your application?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is:

field isParent contains 1

Comment: `[isParent] = "1"` and `field isParent contains 1` mean the same for full text search - it is just another syntax - look here http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/full-text-syntax